# jquery: how can I chain functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i use jquery for a long time and thinking of creating a plugin myself. but no matter how easy the tutorial was, i cant really grasp the idea of chaining. suppose i have this very simple plugin....

```
(function($){
      $.test = function(){

        $.test.one = function(){ alert("1");};

        $.test.two = function(){ alert("2");};

        return this.each(function(){
             (what to write here????)
        });
      };
 })(jQuery);
```

what i want to accomplish is, when i call like eg

```
var myplugin = $.test();
myplugin.one().two();
```

but it returns me errors. sorry, i tried many times googling simple tutorials but i cant get this working

Comment: If you haven't yet, I strongly recommend you to take a look at the jQuery's plugins/authoring guide http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
(function($){
    $.fn.test = function(){
        var self = this;
        this.one = function(){ alert("1"); return self; };
        this.two = function(){ alert("2"); return self; };
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));


var myplugin = $().test();
myplugin.one().two();
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzzMY/

As a side note I strongly suggest this useful resource on the subject : http://jqueryboilerplate.com/

Comment: wow! this works! but can i ask you what is the difference of $.fn.test from $.test?

Comment: $.fn.test is the properly and correct way to add a function to jQuery prototype and thus, create a plugin (while $.test is like just adding a property to jQuery function)

Comment: oh i see, thanks so much man! i will try and look at the link!

Answer (score 1):

here is my plugin template:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.pluginName = function(){

  }
  return this;
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

Never written a jQuery plugin myself but surely you need to return something from your methods `one` and `two` (probably '`this`') or there is no object for the second method in your chain to be called on.